# In Azure, how to return ALL rows across 2 different Log Analytics Workspaces using KQL union?

Tags: union, workspace, azure-log-analytics, kql

I am having trouble with KQL  when using union to include 2 log analytics workspaces.
My task is to count all failed ADFPipelineRun from 2 different Log Analytics Workspaces; A and B

Here is my syntax for running a Kusto query from Log Analytics Workspace A, and include Workspace B:

```
ADFPipelineRun //which is Workspace A
|union 
workspace("<WorkspaceID for workspace B>").ADFPipelineRun 
| where Status == "Failed"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
| summarize CountFailed=count()
```

Problem is it seems some rows are not counted, I suspect the use of union has something to do with it.

If I run the below query first from workspace A and then from workspace B, and then just add the counts, then I can see that using the union is missing approx 20% of the rows in the count.

```
ADFPipelineRun
| where Status == "Failed"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
| summarize Count=count()
```

From KQL-documentation union should return all rows when counting, but that does not happen. Rather it seems union returns distinct row-count.
So, how to return the count of ALL rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [countif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/countif-aggfunction) aggregation function:

```
ADFPipelineRun //which is Workspace A
|union 
workspace("<WorkspaceID for workspace B>").ADFPipelineRun 
| summarize CountFailed = countif(Status == "Failed")
            TimeStatus = countif(TimeGenerated > ago(90d))
```

You can refer to [Kusto | Summarize count() multiple columns with where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417388/kusto-summarize-count-multiple-columns-with-where-clauses), [union operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) and [Combine 2 result set using union in Kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600249/combine-2-result-set-using-union-in-kusto)